# Ionic live reload not working on my android device

Tags: node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Show this error when I live reload on my android device.
[image: Show this error when I live reload on my android device.]

My system information
[image]

Please give me any suggestions.

Comment: delete your node-modules, npm install again.

Comment: I tried but same problem arises.

Comment: delete platform android and do cordova add platform again.

Comment: Thank u but I tried this solution but same problem arises. Some people face the same problem https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/4795.